# How to get button click event of button dynamic buttons on table view cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm working on app having functionality of dynamic number of button in each table view cell. Number of button varies as row wise.

I want to give image a button to click. But I'm not able to get it so any one can help me  to getting changing image of selected button .

Comment: Please show the relevant code for what you have tried :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should add tag to yourButton and assign `indexPath.row` to it in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

```
UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [yourButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    yourButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 30);     
    [cell addSubview:yourButton];
```

After that, define `buttonSelected:` method.

```
-(void)buttonSelected:(id)sender{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"buttonSelectd: %d",button.tag);
   //implement your code what you want.

}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks prasad for your answer i know it works fine but my problem is number of buttons on each cell are different means (cell 1 having 2 buttons ,cell 2 having 6 buttons ) the Number of button is not fixed so i'm having trouble while doing this  here is my sample code for adding button on cell

Comment: for (int i=0; i<[Array count]; i++)
{
    optionButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    optionButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    optionButton.frame=CGRectMake(5,80,22,18);          
    [optionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPresssed:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    optionButton.tag=i;
    [cell addSubview:optionButton];
   }

Comment: The Number of button depends on Array COunt so i'm not able to trace which button clicked and One more thing i have to collect the select buttons value together so please can u tell me how to do this .Thanks in advance